# Undefined cookies

Tags: cookies, nestjs

when I do request with postman code works, but from the front it doesn't.
Problem with undefined oldRefreshToken when I do request from front.
But I don't know why it parse cookies from postman and does not from front :(

Server login part:

```
@Public()
  @Post('login')
  @HttpCode(HttpStatus.OK)
  async signinLocal(
    @Body() dto: AuthDto,
    @Res({ passthrough: true }) response: Response,
  ): Promise<any> {
    const tokens = await this.authService.signinLocal(dto);
    response.cookie('refreshToken', tokens.refreshToken, {
      maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
      httpOnly: true,
    });
    return { accessToken: tokens.accessToken };
  }
```

Server refreshToken part:

```
    @Public()
    @UseGuards(RefreshTokenGuard)
    @Post('refresh')
    @HttpCode(HttpStatus.OK)
    async refreshTokens(
    @GetCurrentUser('sub') userId: number,
    @Req() request: Request,
    @Res({ passthrough: true }) response: Response,
  ): Promise<string> {
    const oldRefreshToken = request?.cookies['refreshToken'];
    const tokens = await this.authService.refreshTokens(
      userId,
      oldRefreshToken,
    );
    response.cookie('refreshToken', tokens.refreshToken, {
      maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
      httpOnly: true,
    });
    return tokens.accessToken;
  }
```

Frontend part:

```
const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/auth/refresh/", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
      },
    });
```

Comment: make sure the cookies you're expecting are being sent by the browser (by looking at network's tab). If the cookies reaches the server, then it will parse it regardless of the HTTP client

Comment: My client accepting the cookies(I see set-cookies in response), but I can't see it in Application page
It looks like my front declines cookies, but I don't know how to solve it

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies maybe some flag is being prevent the cookie from being sent by the client, I'd say.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can't access the token in the frontend, because it's http only (wich means no javascript in the frontend can access the cookie)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).